# changing css style dynamically from component in Angular 5

Tags: angular5, materialized

I am using materialized range:

```
<div class="range-field  col s6">
  <input type="range" id="test5" min="0" max="100"  #ranger (input)="yourMethod(ranger.value)"/>
</div>
```

This input creates in HTML span tag with class thumb, how could I change the color dynamically by changing the range? Is it possible to define in css .thumb {background-color: somevariable}, and change it from the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically set the color in html through a variable defined in the component.

```
<p [style.color]="variable"></p>
```

define the value of variable in component. But make sure you have a default value defined otherwise it will throw an error.